# How to edit registry from Vista recovery tool?

Tags: windows-vista, windows-registry, regedit, system-recovery

How can I edit the registry from the Windows Vista Recovery Tool?

The recovery tool provides 5 options:

- Startup Repair
- System Restore
- Windows Complete PC Restore
- Windows Memory Diagnostic Tool
- Command Prompt

I can click **Command Prompt**, from where I can type:

```
X:\Sources>regedit
```

And **RegEdit** appears. But it is editing the registry of the mini-Windows environment that is running the recovery tool - it's not **my** registry.

I need to edit

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\MUI\UILanguages\xx-YY`

and change it to

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\MUI\UILanguages\`**en-US**

---

### What I tried

I tried creating a dummy key:

```
HKCU\Software\TempTestFoo
```

and then using **File -> Import** to import the registry hive file:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\system
```

and it does, it brings in every key, except **CurrentControlSet**:

```
\CurrentControlSet001
\CurrentControlSet002
\CurrentControlSet003
\LastKnownGoodRecovery
\MountedDevices
\Select
\Setup
\WPA
```

Comment: Wait, if you use Import, doesn't it copy all the information from the hive file into the mini-Windows environment's registry, instead of giving you access to the hive file?

Comment: @ilya No, it "mounts" the hive to a specified key.

Comment: Ah, cool. I thought you have to use "REG LOAD" for that.

Comment: For posterity and @IanBoyd, it actually *does* matter whether you "import" or "load hive". Import only copies sub-keys from a selected hive file and modifying this copy does not change the actual hive you imported from. "Load Hive" does the opposite, and is what you need to do to accomplish what you described. (Tested on Windows Server 2008.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The quick answer, you're pretty much there.  Check value of **`Current`** in the key **`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\Select`**.  This will tell you which of the **`CurrentControlSet00X`**'s you need to make your change in.

For example, if **`Current`** is set to **`2`**, you need to edit **`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet002`** with your changes.

The way it works is this:

Windows always keeps a few copies of this key, suffixed 001 to 003 (only 2 in Windows 7 I think?).  CurrentControlSet001, CurrentControlSet002 and CurrentControlSet003.  Think of them as the master keys that are persistent while the computer is switched off.

When you log into Windows, it picks the last used key, using the value of **`Current`** in the **`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\Select`** key.  The content is copied into a key called **`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet`**.  This key is what Windows plays with while you are logged on.

When you log off of Windows, changes are written back to the key that was original copied from when you first logged on.  **`CurrentControlSet002`** for example.  **`CurrentControlSet`** vanishes, so to speak.  This is why you are unable to see it while you are logged off, working from the recovery console :-)

Probably a bit over the top with my answer (I blame the Red Bull), but I figured I'd answer a detailed question with a detailed answer.

Comment: +1 for thorough answer. Unfortunatly i was able to find the CD with SATA drivers for my motherboard's hard drive controller, and i was able to run the "Repair" option. That is a long way of saying that i wasn't able to text your answer. But it seems reasonable. So "accepted".