# Know of a good replacement for systray.exe?

Tags: windows-xp, notification-area

Necessary background: I'm using [a crippled version of Windows XP](https://superuser.com/questions/178623/setting-language-for-non-unicode-programs-broke-windows) in which explorer.exe will not run, so I've been using the Task Manager's New Task dialog to run programs, copy files, etc. I am unable to reinstall because I cannot find my copy of Windows XP Professional.

I am using a program that is only accessible through the system tray's notification area—those little icons next to the clock. However, one of the consequences of explorer.exe's failure is that I don't have a start menu, system tray, clock, etc., so I can't access this program. Do you know of a program that replicates the behavior of the system tray notification area? Not a dock, necessarily—I can switch between programs just fine; I only need access to the notification icons that would normally hang around next to the clock in traditional XP. I've tried [TrayModule](http://am-productions.biz/getprod.php?pcode=TrayModule) and [AquaDock](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/OS-Enhancements/Aqua-Dock.shtml) unsuccessfully. Any guidance here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just find or download a copy of Windows XP already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While perhaps rather roundabout, I do know that [ObjectDock](http://www.stardock.com/products/objectdock/) has a system tray plugin which will display the icons usually found in the system tray. I *think* [RocketDock](http://rocketdock.com/) also has a system tray plugin (or can use the one from ObjectDock), and is completely free. I've used ObjectDock as a complete replacement for the start menu/task bar/system tray before, and the free/lite version should fulfill your needs.

Comment: Giving RocketDock a shot, first.

Comment: I was able to run RocketDock, and after a little trouble got KkMenu working with it, but I was never able to get KkMenu to actually display a program that should have been running in the system tray. Trying ObjectDock directly now.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the easiest and cheapest solution was to use [EmergeDesktop](http://www.emergedesktop.org/) and disable all aspects of it except for EmergeCore and EmergeTray, with RocketDock for more traditional taskbar activities. So thanks for that, Darth Android! That's why I'm voting your answer up, but not voting up the actual answer: you've made my life a lot easier, if not actually in the way I was intending.

Answer (score 0):

I love the Emerge Systray solution. I use AutoHotKey as some sort of Shell Replacement. I work mostly in Emacs, so I found it a waste of resource to use Explorer as the shell, but I need a Tray,because sometimes an application must use a system tray to fully use it feature