# PC crashes everytime when working on script

Tags: windows-8, crash

I have been experiencing some pc crashes everytime I work on my script (screen scraping with CURL)

I usually have the following programs active, all latest version:

dreamweaver (script editor)

Filezilla Client (ftp)

Some basic folders on desktop

Chrome (browser)

When the crashes happen the monitor screen gets 'scrambled', showing horizontal colorful 'distorted' lines all over my screen then nothing happens. I have to restart my PC and fortunately no data is ever lost.

When I restart however my windows 8 shows me a message giving me the option to send out a error file to microsoft about the crash, it also sums up the reason for the crash:

C:\Windows\Minidump\030913-25147-01.dmp

C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Temp\WER-70512-0.sysdata.xml

C:\Windows\MEMORY.DMP

I can't make heads nor tails out of this. So basically my question is what could have happened? I see  "AppData\Local" Does this mean it involves some App? Could it be some 'evil' malware being injected during my screen scraping work?

ps If this is not a question for Superuser please let me know where to ask this question instead

Thanks to the link provided by @techie007 I downloaded/installed WhoCrashed. The programm was able to produce a crash repport:

```
On Sat 9-3-2013 15:56:39 GMT your computer crashed
crash dump file: C:\Windows\Minidump\030913-25147-01.dmp
This was probably caused by the following module: ntoskrnl.exe (nt+0x7A040) 
Bugcheck code: 0x3B (0xC0000005, 0x115058000, 0xFFFFF8800A68EFC0, 0x0)
Error: SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION
file path: C:\Windows\system32\ntoskrnl.exe
product: Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
company: Microsoft Corporation
description: NT Kernel & System
Bug check description: This indicates that an exception happened while executing a routine that transitions from non-privileged code to privileged code. 
This appears to be a typical software driver bug and is not likely to be caused by a hardware problem. 
The crash took place in the Windows kernel. Possibly this problem is caused by another driver that cannot be identified at this time.
```

So now what do I do..??

Comment: possible duplicate of [I keep getting the BSOD. how do I trace what application / driver is causing it?](http://superuser.com/questions/437057/i-keep-getting-the-bsod-how-do-i-trace-what-application-driver-is-causing-it) also see http://superuser.com/questions/376043/how-to-find-the-source-of-this-bsod-how-to-fix-it/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use an AMD CPU / GPU install this hotfix:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2818604

Comment: ok, this is the answer MS gave me after sending them some dumps. The Update KB2778344 seams to cause the crashes and the AMD microcode update should fix the crash.